# Cambio de nombres en campos Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

en mi tabla users, los campos email y password fueron cambiados a user_email y user_password, ademas de en el fillable y en el name del input en el html donde debo cambiar estos nombres? gracias de antemano
ya que me sigue saltando este error, y cambios en el vendor no debo hacer

> ErrorException

> Undefined index: password

public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)

```
{

    $plain = $credentials['password'];



    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());

}
```

Comment: Recuerda que debes de hacer el ```rollback``` y después ```php artisan migrate``` de lo contrario tus columnas no tendrán ese valor

Comment: Estoy utilizando Laravel Breeze

Comment: listo amigo gracias miren lo que hice(igual comentare la respuesta mas abajo a ver si hay una mejor opcion) 
En mi metodo validateCredential cambie password por user_password
 public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
         $plain = $credentials['user_password']; 

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

Comment: y en getAuthPassword() cambie  return $this->password por  return $this->user_password;

Comment: @JuanMFermin no olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Si alguno tiene una mejor solucion es bienvenida, acá está como pude solventar por ahora

En namespace Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
         $plain = $credentials['user_password']; 

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```

y en namespace Illuminate\Auth\Authenticable;

```
   public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->user_password;
    }
```